# Need code coverage in if ,else blocks

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Hi can anyone help me how to make code coverage for the following scenario?

```
public PageReference doChanges() 
{
    selectedLineItems = getLineItemSelection();

    if(selectedLineItems.size() > 15) 
    {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, system.label.eTools_15_line_Items_Request));
        return null;
    }

    Boolean flag = false;
    flag = cartUtility.QuotePurchaseAndAmendmentProcess('Amendment', SelectedDocsList);

    If(flag != true)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your question: Why are you not able to do it, is anything confusing you or are you receiving any errors that you do not understand ?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest on my issue Samuel. I am not getting any errors but code coverage is not hipping this kind of methods. As I did not write test classes so far I am facing some issues.

Comment: Then, it might be a good idea to describe the 'some issues' you are having in your question, so we can focus on those and explain them rather than just providing some code.

Comment: I am providing getLineItemSelection() functionality.I would be appreciate if you provide some code snippet for code coverage so that I can go forward for similar functionalists.

Comment: public DocumentLineItemWrapper[] getLineItemSelection() {
        DocumentLineItemWrapper[] selectedLineItems = new eDocumentLineItemWrapper[]{};  if(lineItemList==NULL) lineItemList= new List < DocumentLineItemWrapper >();
        for(Integer i=0; i<lineItemList.size(); i++) { 
            DocumentLineItemWrapper lineItemWrap = lineItemList[i];
                        if(lineItemWrap.isSelected==true) lineItemWrap.selectionIndex = (selectedLineItems.size());
       selectedLineItems.add(lineItemWrap);
            }
        }
        
        return selectedLineItems;
    }

Comment: Sanjay, could you update your question with the  additional code and your attempts ? It's best if the question itself represents all info, and nothing is hiden in the comments. This makes it easier for others to comprehend your question. If you're new to stackexchange please have a look at the [welcome tour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

By the way this code not seems correct because there is no `return` statement for case when no one of `if` statement is true. Seems that this code can't be compiled.

Also your code is closed from us because you mentioned 2 methods which were not listed here but the result of these methods is key for understanding how to test this code.

Anyway, you need to test the following scenarios:

instantiate a class which is contain `doChanges()`

- generate 15 line items which will be returned by `getLineItemSelection()`
- generate 16 line items which will be returned by `getLineItemSelection()`

for both cases you need to generate data which will cause for setting `flag` to `true` and to `false`.

So, basically you need 4 test methods and unknown amount of helper methods for generating test data in order to cover this code.